# OnClick não funciona após div receber conteúdo de outra div

Tags: jquery

```
<script>

    $( document ).ready( function ( e ) {

        $( "#idRegiao" ).on( "change", function () {

            if ( $( "#idRegiao" ).val() != "" ) {

                $.ajax( {
                    url: "_scripts/_php/_contagens/contaAreas.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        idRegiao: $( "#idRegiao" ).val()
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $( "#imgCarregando" ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                    },
                    success: function ( result ) {
                        $( "#imgCarregando" ).css( 'display', 'none' );

                        if ( result >= 3 ) $( "#conta" ).html( "<h1>Essa Regiao já possui  " + result + " Áreas!</h1>" );
                        else $( "#conta" ).html( $( "#escolhaArea" ).html() );

                    }

                } );

            } else $( "#conta" ).html( "<h1>Escolha a Região!</h1>" );

        } );


        if ( $( "#idRegiao" ).attr('type') == "hidden" ) $("#idRegiao").trigger("change");
    } );
</script>

<div id="conta"></div>
<div id="escolhaArea" style="display: none;">


    <label class="labelPequeno" for="idLider">Líder</label> :
    <select name="idLider" id="idLider" class="inputTextMedio required">
        <option value="" selected>Escolha o Líder</option>
        <option value=6>Celeste</option><option value=2>Cleonice</option><option value=9>Diana</option><option value=3>Jonas</option><option value=8>José</option><option value=10>Josias</option><option value=4>Tobias</option>       </select> <br/> <label class="labelPequeno" for="nome">Nome da Área</label> : <input type="text" class="inputTextMedio required" name="nome" id="nome" required/> <br/>
    <br/>
    <button id="buttonCadastrarArea" class="button">Cadastrar</button><br/>
    <img id="imgCarregando" style="display: none" src="_imgs/carregando.gif"/>
    <div class="resposta"></div>

</div>
```

Após fazer

```
$( "#conta" ).html( $( "#escolhaArea" ).html() );
```

O

```
<button id="buttonCadastrarArea" class="button">Cadastrar</button>
```

Parou de receber o click.

Porque?

**NAO HÁ ERROS NO CONSOLE**

Comment: Seu código parece ter vários problemas, vou tentar explicar: Se você está criando uma "cópia" do HTML de um elemento em outro não significa que os eventos e outras coisas atreladas ao JS vão ser copiadas tambem. Você está criando uma cópia de um elemento que tem ID, dessa maneira você terá IDs repetidos no seu HTML, isso é sinal que precisa mudar a estratégia.
PS: você poderia também montar um [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que reproduza o problema em um snippet e retirar códigos que não fazem parte do problema, como o spinner de loading. Fica mais fácil de te ajudar

Comment: obrigado pela dica.Entendi a explicação e criei a solução!

Answer (score 0):

Bom, resolvi:

Troquei:

```
if ( result >= 3 ) $( "#conta" ).html( "<h1>Essa Regiao já possui  " + result + " Áreas!</h1>" );
else $( "#conta" ).html( $( "#escolhaArea" ).html() );
```

Por:

```
if ( result >= 3 ) {
    $( "#conta" ).html( "<h1>Essa Rede já possui " + result + " Regiões!</h1>" );
    $( "#conta" ).css( "display", "block" );
    $( "#escolhaRegiao" ).css( "display", "none" );
} else {
    $( "#conta" ).css( "display", "none" );
    $( "#escolhaRegiao" ).css( "display", "block" );
}
```